# Why gamma-matrices are associated with tetrads Lorentz rotation?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-spin, dirac-matrices, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In Zee's "QFT in nutshell" in a paragraph "Differential geometry of Riemann manifold" he states that Dirac gamma-matrices are associated with tetrads Lorentz rotation, so Dirac lagrangian in curved spacetime is written in a form
$$
\tag 1 L =\bar{\psi}\left(i\gamma^{a}\eta_{ab}e^{b}_{\mu}g^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\nu}-m \right)\psi. 
$$
Here $\eta_{ab}$ is Minkowski tensor, $e_{\mu}^{a}$ is tetrad.

Hown to understand that statement? How to associate gamma-matrices with tetrades rotation? How from that statement follows the explicit form of lagrangian $(1)$?

Comment: The gamma matrices are the generators of the Clifford algebra, and hence induce representations of the Lorentz algebra. Just think about it - usually, we'd have $\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu$ there, and the term that is written down there is just the closest generalisation you can find, since, in curved spacetime, the $\gamma$ still carry Lorentz indices while the $\partial$ do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deal with fermion fields in general relativity, that are representations of the Lorentz group, you want to work in a local inertial frame (LIF). To go back and forth between space-time indices $\mu=0,1,2,3$ and LIF indices $a=0,1,2,3$ you introduce the formalism of frame fields:

$$g_{\mu \nu}=e^a_\mu (x) \eta_{ab} e^b_\nu (x)$$

The generalization of gamma matrices to curved space is:

$$\gamma^{\mu}(x)=e_a^\mu (x)\gamma_{a} $$

where $\gamma^{a}$ are the usual constant matrices of quantum field theory in flat space. Dirac action is generalized to:

$$S=\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} (\bar{\psi}e_a^\mu\gamma^{a} D_{\mu} \psi-m\bar{\psi}\psi)$$

In which $D_{\mu}\psi_{\nu}=\partial_{\mu}\psi_{\nu}+\frac{1}{4} \omega_{\mu ab}\gamma^{ab}\psi_{\nu}-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}\psi_{\rho}$ for a spinor-vector field $\psi_{\nu}$. Actually for the spinor case $\psi$ of your question there isn't the $\Gamma $ piece in $D_{\mu}$. $\omega$ is the spin connection.

Reference: Freedman-Van Proeyen, Supergravity, p.178

Comment: Hi, shouldn't actually be $\gamma^\mu (x) = e^\mu_a(x) \gamma^a$ ?